# PL Upload - Displaying a button next to uploaded file in filelist

Tags: javascript, jquery, plupload

I am using PLUpload a fantastic jquery plugin for uploading multiple files. It is working great but i would like to add a delete button next to each file after it has been uploaded.

I am using the Core example.

Is this possible? if so how do i implement it?

My code

```
  var uploaded = {}

            var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({            
              runtimes : 'html5,flash,silverlight',
                 browse_button : 'pickfiles', // you can pass in id...
                container: document.getElementById('container'), // ... or DOM Element itself

            url : 'https://<?= $my_bucket ?>.s3-<?= $region ?>.amazonaws.com/',

            multipart: true,
            multipart_params: {
                'key': '<?=$filepath;?>${filename}',
                'acl': 'public-read',
                'X-Amz-Credential' : '<?= $access_key; ?>/<?= $short_date; ?>/<?= $region; ?>/s3/aws4_request',
                'X-Amz-Algorithm' : 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256',
                'X-Amz-Date' : '<?=$iso_date ; ?>',
                'policy' : '<?=base64_encode($policy); ?>',
                'X-Amz-Signature' : '<?=$signature ?>'
            },

            file_data_name: 'file',

            filters : {
                max_file_size : '30mb',
                mime_types: [
                    {title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,jpeg"},
                    {title : "Audio files", extensions : "mp3,aac"}
                ]
            },

            flash_swf_url : 'Moxie.swf',
            silverlight_xap_url : 'Moxie.xap',


              init: {
        PostInit: function() {
            document.getElementById('filelist').innerHTML = '';

            document.getElementById('uploadfiles').onclick = function() {
                uploader.start();
                return false;
            };
        },

        FilesAdded: function(up, files) {
            plupload.each(files, function(file) {
                document.getElementById('filelist').innerHTML += '<div id="' + file.id + '">' + file.name + ' (' + plupload.formatSize(file.size) + ') <b></b></div>' ;
            });
        },



        UploadProgress: function(up, file) {
            document.getElementById(file.id).getElementsByTagName('b')[0].innerHTML = '<span>' + file.percent + "%</span>";
        },

        Error: function(up, err) {
            document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "\nError #" + err.code + ": " + err.message;
        },

        FileUploaded: function(up, file, info) 

                {
                document.getElementById('filelist').innerHTML += '<button id="' + file.id + '">Delete</button>';
               },
    }
});

uploader.init();
```

Any help will be truly appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your self-assigned task is a generic JavaScript/HTML question rather than specifically related to Plupload. What you should do you say? When files are picked on `FilesAdded` - create an interactive list of files with a remove button for each one, so that when you click it file is removed from the list of files to be uploaded. Core Plupload API doesn't have such functionality built in, you will have to built it yourself on top. Or simply use one of the Plupload widgets, that already have it.

If you are still looking for a way to do it yourself, peek under the hood of Plupload UI plugin [here](https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/blob/master/js/jquery.ui.plupload/jquery.ui.plupload.js#L1129)